# Submit Custom Postypes from frontend

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, forms

I am attempting to create a form that submits data and creates a post with custom fields filled. What I would like to do in step form.

1) Create a custom posttype function called "pickups" (I do not know how to do this)

2) Inside Pickups I need a function to created 5 separate columns which will be populated from the post types custom field.

3) Build a Form that will populate those 5 columns as a new postype(*not sure if that is the correct term*)

4) Then I need to output this data I am assuming with short code to a page.

Here is some code I have found, however parts of it will need to be modified and the postype function will still need to be built.

**pickup.php**

```
<!-- New Post Form -->

<div id="postbox">
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="">
<p><label for="name">Name</label><br />
<input type="text" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="name" />
</p>
<p><label for="address">Address</label><br />
<input type="text" id="address" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="address" />
</p>
<p><label for="Phone">Phone</label><br />
<input type="text" id="Phone" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="Phone" />
</p>
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); //Apparently needed for security ?> 
</form>
</div><!--postbox ends-->

<?
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['name'])) {
        $name =  $_POST['name'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter a name';
    }
    // Repeat this for each input field


    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $post = array(
        'post_name' => $name,
        'post_address'  => $address,
        'post_phone'    => $phone,

    );
    wp_insert_post($post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function
                            // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
} // end IF

// Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post'); 

?>

<!--// New Post Form -->
```

Answer (score 1):

http://wpshout.com/wordpress-submit-posts-from-frontend/

Refer above link, we can check user logged in or not in fronted and pass custom post type too while saving post in database.

Comment: this doesn't have anything about making the custom-postype this just shows how to add to a regular post

Comment: @AndersKitson please read all tutorial , before calling wp_insert_post($post); in $post array you can pass 'post_type' whatever you want ie your custom post type. Its explained there well.

Comment: I have read the whole tutorial, I am still trying to figure out how to create columns in a custom post-type.

Comment: @AndersKitson what you mean 'create columns in a custom post-type.'?

Comment: something like this, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28413/trying-to-save-custom-post-type-from-frontend-partially-working

Comment: @AndersKitson see what i get is add post with custom post_type and it returns post id with the help of that add meta info of that post in post_meta.